# Git rebase pull request

Tags: git, github

I have a pull request accepted for my feature branch, but github is telling me that "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" before I merge it into the master branch. The author of the project would like me to rebase. I'm not sure exactly how to finish this up. This is what I've done so far:

```
git clone theproject
git checkout -b myfeaturebranch origin/myfeaturebranch
git rebase origin/master
[fixed conflicts]
git rebase --continue 
[myfeaturebranch is now good to go..somewhere]
```

What do I do at this point?:

1. Do I push to the remote myfeaturebranch, then create a new pull request there? (I assume github would let me merge via their nice green merge button since there will no longer be any conflicts).
2. Or do I now switch to master locally, merge the local feature branch into it, then push it to remote master branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "The author of the project would like me to rebase".

If they meant that they want you to rebase before you merge it, then you can do your option 2 (making sure that your local `master` is up to date with the remote first).

If you don't have permission to push to `master`, or the author of the project didn't want you to, then you can either:

- push to another remote branch and create a new pull request based on that branch (which will then show the green merge button as you have resolved the conflicts), and then merge in the GitHub UI.
- force push (`git push -f ...`) your rebased branch over the top of the one that is already there. This will update the existing remote branch, and GitHub will notice and should then show that there are no conflicts. Doing it this way will replace the existing branch, so any comments that have been made on the pull request *on specific commits* (i.e. not on the pull request directly) will be lost.

Comment: In my experience the second option is the usual MO. Rebasing is a common way to fix up a pull request in preparation for merging, so creating *another* pull request usually isn't necessary.

Comment: @Caleb Yep, totally agree. I only mentioned it because the OP mentioned creating a new pull request in the question, so it was to draw a distinction between updating the original branch (and hence the PR), and creating a new branch.

Comment: Great, thanks that makes sense - I went with option #2, works great.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you mentioned that it is the author/owner of the project who is asking for the rebase of the feature branch. In such a case, you should finish up by pushing your feature branch. Because of the rebase, you will need to use the `--force` option to push the branch. It is then up to the author to either merge as-is, or re-review and merge.

So, everything you've gone is correct, just run:

`git push -f`

(assumes you have "myfeaturebranch" checked out)

That will push `myfeaturebranch` back up to the remote, overwriting the existing `myfeaturebranch`.

Answer (score -1):

Conflict may happen in rebase, the rebase message will show in which files conflicts exist. Open those files, search for "HEAD <<<<<" tags to find the conflicts and resolve them. The code session under the tag of "HEAD <<<<<" is code on the top of tree (master), while the code right above the tag of " <<<<<" is the code under your commit. After you resolve the conflicts, you have to manually remove those tags and keep/modify only one version of codes.
Then, save the modified files, and type the following commands.

```
  git add <files have been modified> 
  git rebase --continue
```